# Rename a column in sqlite3 database table? (rename_column)

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, sqlite

I have by mistake given a column in my database a wrong name, so I wish to change it. I have run my:

```
bundle exec rake db:migrate
```

I am trying to rename my column with this command:

```
rename_column(Bankline, appendex_number, appendix_number)
```

Taken from here:
http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/SchemaStatements.html#method-i-rename_column

However, my Terminal gives my this error message:

```
-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `Bankline,'
```

Any ideas? I have already tryed these commands:

```
rename_column(bankline, appendex_number, appendix_number)

rename_column(banklines, appendex_number, appendix_number)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is on [the page you link to](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/SchemaStatements.html#method-i-rename_column):

```
rename_column(:banklines, :description, :name)
```

Comment: Thanks for you help. I typed in "rename_column(:banklines, :appendex_number, :appendix_number)", but I still got the error message "-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `:banklines,'"

Comment: You can't just type that in your terminal. You have to create a migration and in your migration you put that code. Check out [the Rails Guides section about migrations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html). Good luck.

Comment: Awesome, that did the job. Sorry about not understanding at first. Now I understand the concept. The database column has been altered successfully. I called the migration RenameDatabaseColumn. Would it have been more appropriate to include the column name and database table name in the migration name?

Comment: I'm glad it's solved. Yes, I think the name `RenameDatabaseColumn` is too generic. Better include column and table names next time.